# In Power Rangers, what are Farkas "Bulk" Bulkmeier and Eugene "Skull" Skullovitch's respective ethnicities?

Tags: power-rangers

I know Paul Schrier (Bulk's actor) and Jason Navry (Skull's actor) are both Ashkenazi Jews in real life.

But, at the same time, I have NEVER saw the surnames Bulkmeier and Skullovitch in real life.

However, Farkas is a name of Hungarian origin, and Eugene is a given name of Greek origin.

Answer (score 1):

Meier is the German word for mayor (also the same exact origin as French *Maire*, which is the Latin word *major*, which means large or big or tall or major or superior).

-Ovitch is a patronymic ending of Slavic origin.

Combined with their respective given name, I think Bulk is a Californian of German, and Hungarian descent (respectively, on his father's side, and on his mother's side), and Skull is a Californian of Serbo-Croatian, Greek, Russian, and Ukrainian descent (respectively, on his paternal grandfather's side, on his paternal grandmother's side, on his maternal grandfather's side, and on his maternal grandmother's side).

Comment: These surnames look made up. Skull- ? Really? Bulk- too I guess, make it some spanglish, just with German and Russian.